# How can I know which property of the ComosDB object was updated within an azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I would like to trigger a notification when the property of an object stored within cosmosDB changes from `status: proposed` to `status: approved`.

At the moment I only get the updated item as part of the Azure Function parameters, so I do not not if its status was just changed of if the update was about something else.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Cosmos DB Document Change Trigger With Old and new document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57726254/azure-cosmos-db-document-change-trigger-with-old-and-new-document)

Comment: I believe this will eventually be possible with full fidelity change feed https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/2142 but until then change feed is just based on ordering documents by LSN of their last write and has no info about what the write was.